# Was ist die Bedeutung für dickfällig?

Tags: vocabulary

Ich finde es [hier](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/beruf-chance/campus/plagiat-doktorarbeiten-konsequenzen-debora-weber-wulff-13536368.html) aber ich kann nicht die Bedeutung im Worterbuch finden.

> Abkupfern werde *dickfällig* hingenommen

Comment: Kein wunder, dass du es nicht findest - es wird "dickfellig" geschrieben.

Comment: @5pike Hast du den Artikel auf http://www.faz.net/ gelesen ?

Comment: Ja. Schau nochmal zum Artikel. Die haben es dort auch ausgebessert.

Comment: Apparently *dickfällig* is a not so uncommen misspelling (maybe from the analogy to *schwerfällig*), hence your question is of general interest and it **should stay** but it does need the misspelling then (I therefore rolled the dit back).

Comment: Interessant! Ich kenne das Wort nicht.Mit "ä" habe ich es trotz Kontext nicht wirklich erschließen können, mit "e" scheint es sofort klar :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Wort "[dickfellig](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dickfellig)" bedeutet:

> gleichgültig, unempfindlich gegenüber Aufforderung, Missbilligung o. Ä.

Comment: You should add that *dickf**ä**llig* seems to be a common misspelling.